# Scope when calling nested Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I use JS on a website, I often like to split up the code into logical, complete modules using function(), usually like so:

```
function BigClass() {
    this.doOneThing = function() {
    }
    this.doAnother = function() {
    }
}
```

Later I use jQuery's .ready() to create instances of the classes I'm using and hang those onto various events.

```
var bigClassInstance = new BigClass();
$('a.something').click(bigClassInstance.doOneThing);
```

My question is... what's the best way to do execute the *doAnotherThing()* function from  my call to *doOneThing()*? Working on smaller projects, I'll just use *bigClassInstance.doAnotherThing();*, but that's not portable.

What's the Right Way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the problem, but by using the [proxy](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function you can change the context for the function called by the click handler i.e. make `this` refer to your `bigClassInstance` and not the jQuery click context:

```
function BigClass() {
    this.doOneThing = function() {
       this.doAnother();
    }
    this.doAnother = function() {
    }
}

$('a.something').on( "click", $.proxy( bigClassInstance.doOneThing, bigClassInstance ) );
```